# Dynamic channel subscription with in-app subscriptions

Tags: ios, video-streaming, channel, in-app-subscription

I'm trying to implement a video streaming app like YouTube where users can to subscribe to channels by paying. The channels can be created dynamically. I need to implement subscription using Apple in-app subscriptions. As far as I understand we have to create a subscription item for each channel in App Store Connect.
But there can be any number of channels in my app. Is it possible to implement the channel subscription with one subscription item in App Store Connect?